# Can I tell prin1-to-string to use reader-macros?

Tags: quote, print

I'm writing a lispy documentation engine with elisp and to make things easier, I'm trying to modify the following behavior

```
(prin1-to-string '(cons 'a 'b))
;; => "(cons (quote a) (quote b))"
```

to be

```
(prin1-to-string '(cons 'a 'b))
;; => "(cons 'a 'b)"
```

Is it possible to instruct `prin1-to-string` to reinstate reader macros like this?  Reading through the C sources, I don't think it's possible since by the time the object has been read, we've already *used* the reader-macro to turn `'a` into `(quote a)` and that `'` is lost forever.  Is my only hope regex-replace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just bind `print-quoted` to a non-nil value around the call to prin1(-to-string).

Comment: Wow, thanks! Looks like this behavior is defined in `print.c:print_object`'s `Lisp_Cons` case. That function is getting too big :)